# Python Form Processing Problem

Tags: python, cgi

I am a newbie. I wanted to know how to handle array based fields in CGI?

```
<form name="frmLogin" method="get" action="">
Username: <input type="text" name="login[username]" /><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="login[password]" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="login[submit]" />
</form>
```

I have a form like above.
How can I get the login field as a dictionary where keys will be username, password, submit with their corresponding values.

i can get individually by this => form["login[username]"].value
but what if I dont know the key, i.e checkbox[]
Do I need to process the posts and manipulate by manual coding or there is any other way to do it?

in php $_GET['login'] will give me the array of defined key value pair, I need something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain why would you need that? From the `login[xxx]` sample you provided I see no difference between suggested `form["login"]["username"]` and available `form["login[username]"]` or, better, `form["login_username"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `cgi.FieldStorage` has a similar method as the one you describe in php. However, you could write something like this to accomplish the same thing, given the *name[attr]* format you have on your field names:

```
def get(form, prefix):
    output = {}
    def parse(key):
        name = key.split('[')[1].rstrip(']')
        output[name] = form[key]
    map(parse, [key for key in form.keys() if key.startswith(prefix)]
    return output
```

So, your in cgi it would look something like:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
login_info = get(form, 'login')
print login_info['username']
print login_info['password']
```

Comment: Thanks mark, I am thinking same after searching a while. Just it would have been wonderful to be sure that there is no built-in for this.